# Unable to Include Font Awesome in Laravel

Tags: laravel, npm, font-awesome, laravel-mix

I am new to Laravel and have just started learning about views, routes, migrations, etc. I tried to include the Font Awesome CSS library using the `link` statement, but that didn't work. I found an answer on Stack Overflow that used npm but got an error running `npm run dev` that was marked as the solved answer. I also tried to use `{{ asset() }}` as well as several other functions but none of those worked.

What should I do?

Comment: please mention where is your font awesome css files are located and you are using laravel mix or gulp or grunt in resource/assests or directly using css in public folder?

Comment: My font-awesome folder is located in public/ **new_dedicated_folder** and yes I am directly using css in public folder.

Comment: You've tried `<link href="{{ asset('new_dedicated_folder/font-awesome.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`?

Comment: yes, I have and it didn't work. It shows net_err_aborted error.

Comment: What happens if you try to access the CSS directly via e.g. `example.com/new_dedicated_folder/font-awesome.css` ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in the url method.

```
<link href="{{ url('new_dedicated_folder/font-awesome.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

put inside in head tag

if u use cdn

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

if u use local copy

```
 <link href="/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

make sure youre fontawesome copy is inside of public/css directory